# Hyperbolic geometry question concerning lengths between parallel lines

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, proof-explanation, noneuclidean-geometry

Theorem (H16). 
If:

1. $l$ and $m$ are parallel lines,
2. $j$ is a common perpendicular intersecting $l$ at point A and $m$ at point B, and
3. C and E are points on $l$ so that C is between A and E,

Then:

1. $L$(C; m) > $L$(AB);

and

2. $L$(E; m) > $L$(C; m).

I wish I knew how to even begin this proof, but I'm really not sure how to. Can anyone please offer me some help or advice on how I can approach this proof?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by parallel? Nonintersecting? Or what?

Comment: Nonintersecting

Comment: If you say only "nonitersecting" then the common perpedicular may not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Just as similar questions with Euclidean geometry are done with ordinary trigonometry, this is easy to do with hyperbolic trigonometry. Here's a [web link](http://www.maths.gla.ac.uk/wws/cabripages/hyperbolic/hypertrig.html), but I would recommend getting a textbook such as [Ratcliffe's book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387331972).